# ZMQ Nodejs binding - ZMQ_POLLIN/POLLOUT values

Tags: node.js, sockets, zeromq

I'm inspecting these values to understand when I can shut down a socket (that is, when the socket is not polling/sending anything, thus I'm not loosing messages).

I'm using a sender (`zmq.socket('push');`) and a receiver (`zmq.socket('pull');`), but inspecting the `zmq` object I always have these values for `ZMQ_POLLIN` and `ZMQ_POLLOUT` (even if I manually remove the connection, thus no message should be received or sent):

```
{
   ...
   ZMQ_POLLIN: 1,
   ZMQ_POLLOUT: 2,
   ...
}
```

Which doesn't make sense to me. How can I check how a socket is not receiving anything so that I'm sure I can shut it down without worries of loosing incoming/outgoing messages?

Thanks

Comment: Go through this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676617/how-to-push-data-from-c-sharp-to-zeromq-and-pull-from-node-js-or-vice-versa) and the links in the question you will get some idea..

Comment: I'm not trying to set up the connection. I'm trying to know when the socket will not receive messages anymore - i.e. I can kill the socket without loosing messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking indeed at the wrong function. What I had to look at was `getsockopt(zmq.ZMQ_EVENTS);`. The function has to be called from either the sender or the receiver in my case, and the result must be bitwise ANDed with the actual value of the constants zmq.ZMQ_POLLIN or zmq.ZMQ_POLLOUT.

To check if a socket is receiving messages I do like this: `receiver.getsockopt(zmq.ZMQ_EVENTS) | zmq.ZMQ_POLLIN == 0`, but having the result `>0` doesn't mean it is receiving messages, it just means the queue is not full.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think those constants mean what you think they mean. They are meant to be passed to the `zmq.poll()` function (or some such, I don't know the Node.js versions) as an interest specification. You then want to inspect the return value(s) from the `poll()` call to see if the sockets are still active.