# How to Push data from C# to ZeroMQ and Pull from Node.JS or vice-versa?

Tags: c#, node.js, client-server, zeromq

**Scenario**:

I am trying to send a data (say `String` type)  from C# сonsole application to Node.JS server through ZeroMQ.

**Information:**

Using clrzmq for c# and ZeroMQ libs for C# and Node.JS respectively

I am able to perform [push-pull](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node/blob/master/examples/push_pull.js) from Node.JS, also [push](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq#example-client) - [pull](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq#example-server) from C#.

So, one thing is confirmed that [ZeroMQ - The Intelligent Transport Layer](http://www.zeromq.org/) is installed on the machine (Windows 7 64-bit)

**Issue**:

I am not able to push data from C# Console app to Node.JS app (even tried vice-versa), both are on the same machine and on the same address i.e `tcp://127.0.0.1:2222`

Node.js code:

```
var zmq = require('zeromq.node');
var pull_socket = zmq.socket('pull');    
pull_socket.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:2222');    
pull_socket.on('message', function (data) {
    console.log('received data:\n');
    console.log(data);
});
```

C# code:

```
namespace DataServiceEngine
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //clsApp App = new clsApp();
            //App.appId = "001";
            //App.name = "Back Office";

            //Console.WriteLine("appId :" + App.appId + "\n");
            //Console.WriteLine("name:" + App.name + "\n");

            try
            {
                // ZMQ Context and client socket
                using (var context = new Context(1))
                {
                    using (Socket client = context.Socket(SocketType.PUSH))
                    {
                        client.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:2222");

                        string request = "Hello";
                        for (int requestNum = 0; requestNum < 10; requestNum++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Sending request {0}...", requestNum);
                            client.Send(request, Encoding.Unicode);

                            string reply = client.Recv(Encoding.Unicode);
                            Console.WriteLine("Received reply {0}: {1}", requestNum, reply);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (ZMQ.Exception exp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exp.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Question**: Can anyone tell me what may be the reason or where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Question **should not** be a FAQ regarding the topic. No project home page and wikipedia links are necessary. Thank you for understanding. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue (but I issued a communication Node.JS -> Node.JS). To solve the problem I used to do `sendersocket.connect("tcp://"+host+":"+port);` at the sender and `receiversocket.bindSync("tcp://*:"+port);` at the receiver.

Hope this fix your problem.